# how to make a clean flat cut in sculpt mode and close the resulting edge loop?

Tags: sculpting, remesh

Currently I am sculpting for a 3d print but I need to make a clean cut at the bottom as shown so that the first layer adheres to the print bed. What steps do I take to make it flat at the bottom and close the resulting edge loop?
THanks
[image: clean_cut]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the *Line Project* tool allows you to cut off along a straight line, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to make it perpendicular to the view, move the cursor a bit and press <kbd>F</kbd> to invert the part that will be cut off:

[image]

Comment: @moonboots...wow thats very useful! Under my nose. many thanks!